# How can I test a Singleton class with DUnit?

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, tdd, singleton, dunit

Or it's better to use another Design Pattern?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Responded to a similar question some days ago [here, mocking a Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601073/nunit-mocking-not-working-for-singleton-method/1601438#1601438). The original post is for C#.Net as regards mocking a singleton's behaviour, but should still apply.

As regards the singleton pattern, there isn't anything wrong with it per se - in many cases we want to centralize logic and data. However, there is a very big difference between a singleton and a static class. Building your singleton as a static class hard codes that implementation to every consumer in your application - which makes unit testing very difficult!

What you want to do is define an interface for your singleton, exposing the methods for your consumers to use. Your consumers in turn are **passed** a reference to an implementing class by whomever instantiates them [typically this is your application, or a container if you are familiar with Dependency Injection\Inversion of Control].

It's this framework, whomever is instantiating the consumers, that is responsible for ensuring one and only one instance is floating around. It's really not that great a leap from static class to interface reference [as demonstrated in link above], you just lose the convenience of a globally accessible instance - i know i know, global references are terribly seductive, but Luke turned his back to the Dark Side, so can you!

Generally speaking, best practices suggest avoiding static references, and encourages progamming against interfaces. Remember, it is still possible to apply the singleton pattern with these constraints. Follow these guidelines, and you should have no problem unit testing your work :)

Hope this helps!

---

**singleton != public static class**, rather **singleton == single instance**

Answer (score 3):

Lack of testability is one of the major downfalls of the classic Singleton model (static class method returning an instance). As far as I'm concerned, that's justification enough to re-design any code that uses Singletons to use some other design.

If you absolutely need to have a singular instance, then Dependency Injection and writing to an interface, as suggested by johnny g, is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

[I'm using the following pattern](http://dev.bostone.us/2009/08/17/writing-junit-friendly-static-code/) when I write a static-based singletons that I can mock. The code is Java, but I think you will get an idea. The main problem with this approach is that you have to relax constructor to package-protected (which sorta defeats a true singleton).
As a side note - the code applies to ability to mock your "static" code not necessarily simply calling it

Answer (score 1):

I generally only use Singletons for Flyweight objects or similar value objects.  Looking into an IoC container (as discussed above) is probably a better way to handle a shared object than a singleton.

Consider that in Smalltalk (where a lot of these patterns originated), true and false were both effectively singletons :)

Comment: ... regarding Smalltalk: yes, but true and false are _so_ testable :)

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a singleton (and there are reasons to do so...but I would always try to avoid it if possible). I would recommend using a IOC container to manage it. Im not sure if there is one for Delphi or not. But in Java you could use Spring, in .NET you can use Windsor/Castle. A IOC container can hold onto the Singleton and can register different implementations for testing.

It's probably too big of a subject to get into here beyond this snippet.